# How to make Easing effect for Dreamweaver Image Rollovers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dreamweaver, rollover-effect

When i add image rollover effect using dreamweaver, dreamweaver adds this piece of code as javascript:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
</script>
```

And this in its body `onload`:-

```
<body onload="MM_preloadImages('aim-hover.png')">
```

And this for image rollover:-

```
<a href="#" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image1','','aim-hover.png',1)"><img src="aim.png" name="Image1" width="30" height="30" border="0" id="Image1" /></a>
```

Doing this makes the rollover effect, which switches between images.

**Now my question is:- How i can add `ease-in` `ease-out` effect for these images?**

May be through jquery or pure Javascript......

As in CSS we do something like this for `ease`

```
div {
    position:relative;
    width:240px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    -o-transition:background-color 200ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:background-color 200ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:background-color 200ms ease-in-out;
    transition:background-color 200ms ease-in-out;
}
div:hover {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

`<div></div>​`

Comment: I am also looking for its answer... is there any way??

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a specifically (cross-platform) Javascript solution?

If not, you can easily do it in pure CSS3. Although IE has no love for `transitions`. D:

You can try setting the CSS like so:

```
div.roller { width: 50px; height: 50px; border: solid 1px green;}

div.roller div { -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; width: 50px; height: 50px; }

div.off, div.roller:hover div.over { opacity: 1.0; }

div.roller:hover div.off, div.over { opacity: 0; }

.off { background-color: red; position: absolute;}

.over { background-color: yellow; }
```

Add the browser specific prefixes for `transitions`, I just used `-webkit-` for convenience.

You can set your images as the background of the `.off` and `.over` divs, embed them inside, or even use `img` tags instead of `div` tags.

Make sure to set the element with your initial up state, `.off`, to `position: absolute` so it stacks on top of the down state, `.over`.

And the html like so:

```
<div class="roller" >
    <div class="off">off</div>
    <div class="over">over</div>
</div>​
```

Fiddle with it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jpJUv/).